# Fix spacing around an image using the .thumbnail class in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap v2.3.1, and I am trying to understand how to fix one of my images.

In the example image link below, the top image is what I want all the images to look like when the screen is resized to it's smallest size (cellphone size), and the bottom image is what's giving me an issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxIaS.jpg

For some reason it has more space on the sides of the 2nd image than it should have.

(NOTE: My screenshot is altered to show both the correct image and the wrong image. The code below is what I am actually using)

My code is this:

```
<section>
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li>
            <a class="thumbnail" rel="group" href="images/r1.jpg">
                <img src="images/thumbnails/r1s.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="thumbnail" rel="group" href="images/r2.jpg">
                <img src="images/thumbnails/r2s.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

So I don't know if it's an issue with one of the settings in the CSS file, but since I am using the .thumbnail class, I'm guessing it has to do with that?

Does anyone know how to make it so that I don't get all that extra space around my images when using the .thumbnail class?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is set the CSS to the `<ul class="thumbnails">` with `style="max-width: 100px"` where `100px` is smallest width size of image in list.